# How do I fill the text area using controller method on button click in MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, active-directory

I have created PowerShell scripts to fetch the active directory groups, when the webpage loads the group names fill into the dropdown list. The next thing I am trying to do is using the search button click event, load the group details into the text area and members into the table by passing the PowerShell scripts. I am using the library System.Management.Automation to deal with the PowerShell scripts. As I am dealing directly with PowerShell I don't want my project to depend on any model class. So, I am carrying out interaction between my controller & view only.

**Controller Code:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Linq;
using System;

namespace MyProject.UI.MVC5.Controllers
{
    public class GroupController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Group/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GroupReview()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Group Review";
            ViewBag.Domains = PowerShellExecutorLst(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Shell\\Get-ADDomain.ps1");
            ViewBag.Groups = PowerShellExecutorLst(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Shell\\Get-ADStewardGroups.ps1");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FillDetails(string GroupName)
        {
            ViewBag.SDC = PowerShellExecutorStr(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Shell\\Get-SDC.ps1 '"+ GroupName +"'");
            return View();
        }

        // Fetching DropDownItems from Powershell Script Output
        public List<SelectListItem> PowerShellExecutorLst(string scriptPath)
        {
            string outString = "";
            var shell = PowerShell.Create();
            shell.Commands.AddCommand(scriptPath);
            var results = shell.Invoke();
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                var builder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var psObj in results)
                {
                    builder.Append(psObj.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
                }
                outString = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
            }
            List<string> result = outString.Split(new char[] { '\n' }).ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> listItems = result.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s, Text=s }).ToList();
            shell.Dispose();
            return listItems;
        }
        //Fetching String Values from Powershell Script Output
        private string PowerShellExecutorStr(string script)
        {
            string outString = "";
            var shell = PowerShell.Create();
            shell.Commands.AddCommand(script);
            var results = shell.Invoke();
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                var builder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var psObj in results)
                {
                    builder.Append(psObj.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
                }
                outString = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
            }
            shell.Dispose();
            return outString;
        }
    }
}
```

**View Code:**

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlDirectory", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.Domains, "Select Domain", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="width:auto">
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlGroup", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.Groups, "Select Group", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="focus-link theme-bg-medium-blue reopen-shim">
        <a class="arrow-link theme-bg-color" id="btnSearch" data-form-method="get" type="submit" style="width:auto;" 
           tabindex="14" onclick="">search</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="focus-link theme-bg-medium-blue reopen-shim">
        <a id="btnReset" class="arrow-link theme-bg-color" data-form-method="get" type="submit" style="width:auto;" tabindex="15">reset</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@* Group Details to be filled*@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 lnkLabel">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="lnkDirectory" class="modal-window-sm lnkLabel" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalAppList" tabindex="64" data-targeturl="@Url.Action("ShowModal", "Help", new HelpContentListViewModel() { Tag = "Directory" })">Stewardship Information</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.TextArea("txtSDC",null, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "7", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 lnkLabel">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="lnkDirectory" class="modal-window-sm lnkLabel" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalAppList" tabindex="64" data-targeturl="@Url.Action("ShowModal", "Help", new HelpContentListViewModel() { Tag = "Directory" })">Business Purpose</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.TextArea("txtBusinessPurpose", "This is the text Area Created for the Business Purpose of the group.", new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "6", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@* Result Grid with the list of members *@
<div>
     Code to fill data in HTML Table or WebGrid
</div>
```

In the scripts I am just using normal commands like get-ADUser & get-ADGroup, I need to pass the text of dropdown as a parameter in the FillDetails() controller function but how to load the details in the text area when click event occurs?

I am invoking the PowerShellExecutorStr function to fetch values in the FillDetails() function , I just want to load the values in the dedicated areas if possible using Viewbag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling this script onClick event of Button in

```
@section scripts{
<script>
        function GetGroupDetails()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Group/FillDetails",
                data: { GroupName: $("#ddlGroup option:selected").text().trim()} ,
                success: function (response) {        
                        $("#txtSDC").val(response.message);                   
                }
             });

        }

</script>
}
```

However, controller method needs to return Json result

```
public JsonResult FillDetails(string GroupName)
        {
            var SDC = PowerShellExecutorStr(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Shell\\Get-SDC.ps1 '" + GroupName + "'");
            return Json(new { message = SDC }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```